# Removing page numbers from a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, file, file-io, text-files

I am trying to load a .txt file of an ebook and remove lines that contain page numbers.  The book looks like:

```
2
Words
More words.

More words.

3
More words.
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
x = 1

with open("first.txt","r") as input:
    with open("last.txt","wb") as output: 
        for line in input:
            if line != str(x) + "\n":
                output.write(line + "\n")
                x + x + 1
```

My output file comes out with all of the white space (new lines) removed (which I don't want) and it does not even remove the numbers.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting `x + x + 1` to do?

Comment: Oops, I meant: x = x + 1.  Still, correcting that didn't fix either problem (the white space or the not removing any numbers).  I did it that way because once it's found a page number (e.g. page 1) I want it to look for the next one (e.g. page 2).  This will also help in case for some reason the book has a whole line with just a number that isn't a page number but is really part of the book.

Comment: You can also use `x += 1`. But what if, per the example, it doesn't start at page 1?

Comment: Totally reasonable, I just figured I'd edit it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You don't have to open your file for binary `open("last.txt","wb")` -> `open("last.txt","w")`
2) `x + x + 1` -> `x += 1`

But, you could do it far simpler

```
with open("first.txt","r") as input:
    with open("last.txt","w") as output: 
        for line in input:
            line = line.strip() # clear white space
            try: 
                int(line) #is this a number ?
            except ValueError:
                output.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: you don't have to `strip` and append `\n`, `int('2\r\n')` evaluates to `2`. Also, bare except clause should never appear in code. [Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). You should make it explicit - `int()` method would raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: It can be \s2\s not \r\n. What other exception (that we care of) can int(line) throw ?

Comment: I'm not sure what `\s` means. `int()` can handle arbitrary amount of leading and trailing characters listed in `string.whitespace`. About exceptions - `ìnt()` can also throw `TypeError`, but never in this context (lines are always strings). Interpreter can also raise `KeyboardInterrupt` which would be silented by you. And you never want to do that.

Comment: \s as in whitespace. I didn't know about the handling of whitespace, noted. Regarding the exception, in this particular example, it's quite innocuous (we are trying to show a way). Nevertheless, I'll edit it.

Comment: This works great on my file.  Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Improved solution - one less indentation level, avoid unnecessary `strip` and string summation, explicit exception caught.

```
with open("first.txt","r") as input_file, open("last.txt","w") as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        try: 
            int(line)
        except ValueError:
            output_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can convert the line to an integer and skip this line if that succeeds. Not the quickest solution, but should work.

```
try:
   int(line)
   # skip storing that line
   continue
except ValueError:
   # save the line to output
```

Comment: Too late, Tasos' answer is exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to ignore lines that contain just a number.

```
import sys
import re

pattern = re.compile("""^\d+$""")

for line in sys.stdin:
    if not pattern.match(line):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: You should make that string raw, not multiline: `r"^\d+$"`.